# PDF batch conversion from sRGB to CMYK

Tags: batch-file, pdf, rgb, ghostscript, cmyk

I was trying to convert multiple PDF files with GhostScript from sRGB color space to CMYK. I've used the commands I've found on the Internet:

```
 "C:\Program Files\gs\gs9.18\bin\gswin64c.exe" ^
 -o cmyk.pdf ^
 -sDEVICE=pdfwrite ^
 -sProcessColorModel=DeviceCMYK ^
 -sColorConversionStrategy=CMYK ^
 -sColorConversionStrategyForImages=CMYK ^
 0115000000C.PDF
```

However, after running this script on the file, it's still unconverted -- see the console output ('identify' command from ImageMagic still says 'sRGB'):

[image: console output]

I guess it might have something to do with text in the PDF file, as I was reading about issues with "rich black" color, but I have no idea how to work-around it. Please, is there anyone who can help?

The file I've used to test sRGB->CMYK conversion: [here](https://www.wetransfer.com/downloads/7343d0ba70583701df15c20653476ca420160711153308/979916)

Answer (score 0):

First off, you aren't converting the PDF file, you are making a new one. Look at the Overview in vectordevioces.htm to see why.

Without seeing a source file its impossible to tell what may be happening. And I'm not certain I trust 'identify' either.

And you should probably upgrade, teh current version is 9.19

Comment: The source file is attached, in my first post and here: [link](https://www.wetransfer.com/downloads/7343d0ba70583701df15c20653476ca420160711153308/979916). 
In my understanding, creating a new file but with changed color space, that's also the conversion :) 
Upgrade - yes, I might have missed it - already upgraded. Still, new version did not help, new file which should be converted is still sRGB.

Comment: Sorry I missed the link on my first perusal. I ran the file you supplied here, using your command line, and the resulting PDF file does not contain any RGB (NB the original input file contains RGB, not sRGB). The gray colour space is unchanged but all the RGB colorus have been converted to CMYK. As a check I used the released 9.19 build and it produces the same result. I'm not familiar with 'identify' but I believe it is not telling you what you think it is, or it is simply incorrect. The file I get as output does not contain RGB.

Comment: I have met another issue - in the converted file, the "text" layer seems not to understand CMYK, and while printed, ‘places’ the color as Greyscale and is extremely pixelled/blurred in quality. 
The software used to print is ESKO Artpro 11.5.

Comment: If the text started in gray, it stays in gray. We don't convert DeviceGray into CMYK (or RGB for that matter), there's no point since any sensible interpreter will map gray to Black. There is no text 'layer', there's just text. You seem to be complaining about the way the PDF is printed, rather than the content of the PDF itself. I cannot help you with a proprietary printing system, you would have to take that up with the manufacturer. The PDF I get here has the text in either pure black or pure white, and retained as text using a CIDFont.

Comment: @Bart have you managed to fix how DeviceGray is printed? I've just [digged into](https://bugs.ghostscript.com/show_bug.cgi?id=700843) this, and it looks like Adobe products follow the same logic (at least partially) - they do not convert DeviceGray. It looks like it is really treated as one of the most basic things, not like something user might want to convert.